# Insert multiple values to SQL table (loop like)

Tags: t-sql

I'm using TSQL.

I have two tables - asset_to_role and asset_to_payoff, both with 2 columns.
I need to insert values for an asset to both tables.
For asset_to_role table I need to insert 5 values (312, 315, 316, 318, 319).
For each of those values I need to insert 5 values to asset_to_payoff table (2241, 2242,..., 2245).
To illustrate what I mean here is an example of such insertion:

```
insert into asset_to_role values (asset_id, 312)
insert into asset_to_payoff values (asset_id, 2241)
insert into asset_to_payoff values (asset_id, 2242)
insert into asset_to_payoff values (asset_id, 2243)
insert into asset_to_payoff values (asset_id, 2244)
insert into asset_to_payoff values (asset_id, 2245)
```

Is there a method in SQL to perform the process in a repetitive manner?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: How asset_id is generated? Auto increment?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: @Popeye asset_id is given to me. Assume it is an arbitrary number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have DML trigger could help you on that, you could use After Insert trigger so when you insert data into main table, the trigger will fire and do the rest of tasks.

```
CREATE TABLE asset_to_role (asset_id INT, VALUE INT)
CREATE TABLE asset_to_payoff (asset_id INT, VALUE INT)

GO
CREATE TRIGGER InsertTrigger ON asset_to_role
AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN 
insert into asset_to_payoff SELECT asset_ID,2241 FROM inserted
insert into asset_to_payoff SELECT asset_ID,2242 FROM inserted
insert into asset_to_payoff SELECT asset_ID,2243 FROM inserted
insert into asset_to_payoff SELECT asset_ID,2244 FROM inserted
insert into asset_to_payoff SELECT asset_ID,2245 FROM inserted
END

INSERT INTO dbo.asset_to_role VALUES (1,312)

SELECT * FROM dbo.asset_to_role
SELECT * FROM dbo.asset_to_payoff
```

the result would be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You *could* write a explicit `while` loop, you could also declare a table variable `@input` with your `asset_id` values. Creating all records can then be handled with just 2 `insert` statements.

**Sample data**

```
create table asset_to_role
(
  asset_id int,
  prop1 int
);

create table asset_to_payoff
(
  asset_id int,
  prop2 int
);
```

**Solution**

```
-- define input
declare @input table
(
  asset_id int
);

insert into @input (asset_id) values
(100000), (100001), (100002), (100003); -- list of "arbitrary numbers" goes here...

-- insert role
insert into asset_to_role (asset_id, prop1)
select i.asset_id, 312
from @input i;

-- insert payoff
insert into asset_to_payoff (asset_id, prop2)
select i.asset_id, v.prop2
from @input i
cross join (values (2241), (2242), (2243), (2244), (2245)) as v(prop2);
```

**Result**

```
asset_id prop1
-------- -----
100000   312
100001   312
100002   312
100003   312

asset_id prop2
-------- -----
100000   2241
100000   2242
100000   2243
100000   2244
100000   2245
100001   2241
100001   2242
100001   2243
100001   2244
100001   2245
100002   2241
100002   2242
100002   2243
100002   2244
100002   2245
100003   2241
100003   2242
100003   2243
100003   2244
100003   2245
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=34d67243cfac391532de0462cf530a1c) to see things in action.